# How to test drop zone Vue3 component in Cypress?

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I have this Vue3 component and I'm trying to test if the dropped files are emitted, but it does not work.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emits = defineEmits<{
    (event: 'updateFile', file: File): void
}>();

function handleDropFile(event: DragEvent) {
    draggedOver.value = false;
    if (event.dataTransfer) {
        for (let i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
            const currentFile = event.dataTransfer.files[i];
            if (isFileTypeValid(currentFile.type, props.acceptedFileTypes)) {
                emits('updateFile', currentFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <label
        :id="`${uuid}-dropzone-container`"
        class="drop-zone-container"
        :class="{'dragging': draggedOver}"
        dropzone="copy"
        :for="`${uuid}-input`"
        @dragenter.prevent="draggedOver = true"
        @dragstart.prevent="draggedOver = true"
        @dragover.prevent="draggedOver = true"
        @dragleave.prevent="draggedOver = false"
        @dragend.prevent="draggedOver = false"
        @drop.prevent="handleDropFile"
        data-test="we-drop-zone"
    >
    </label>
    <input 
        :id="`${uuid}-input`"
        :accept="acceptedTypeStr"
        :multiple="multipleFilesAllowed"
        type="file"
        @click.prevent=""
        data-test="we-drop-zone-input"
    />
</template>
```

And this is the Cypress test:

```
it('emits the uploaded file', () => {
    const onUpdateFile = cy.spy().as('onUpdateFile');
    cy.mount(() => (
        <WEDropZone
            uuid='001'
            onUpdateFile={onUpdateFile}
        />
    ));
    cy.get(inputSelector).selectFile({
        contents: imagePath,
        fileName: imageName 
    }, {force: true})
    .then($input => {
        const input = $input as JQuery<HTMLInputElement>;
        const image = input.prop('files')[0];
        cy.get('@onUpdateFile').should('be.calledOnceWithExactly', image);
    });
});
```

I know that in my test I'm trying to get the files from the input, but the emit happens in the drop event handler, which is on the label.

What solution do I have to make the component testable? Setting the events on the input would break my layout and styles, making it harder to hide the input (it must be hidden because the dropzone must contain another elements (text and icon)) and style it according to specifications.

Just to mention, that is not the full component, but I have removed the the unrelated code.